# Windows 7 Scheduled Task with alternate credentials - Admin

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task on a win 7 box that runs under alternate permissions. The account that created the scheduled task was a local admin on the PC, but now the company is removing accounts from being local admins.

The alternate credentials for the one task is needed to run the task under an account with elevated network permissions.

Since removing the admin rights for the account, it can no longer see the scheduled task. The account can see another scheduled task that runs under the account's own credentials.

The account is listed as the owner of both tasks, even though the one runs with alternate credentials.

Any ideas on why it can't see the other task or ways to setup the task so it can without being an admin?

Comment: What is "it"? The computer?

Comment: Sorry - "it" is the account that created both the tasks that was a local admin before. I updated question.. yeah didn't realize how many times I used "it". :)